# Log output HAL in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an image processing application by using android ndk.

I am getting this log and application terminates

```
01-15 04:48:54.860: D/HAL(16913): [HAL] hw_get_module:share library path:/system/lib/hw/gralloc.tegra.so
```

Thanks for any idea,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that your Android OS does not have the shared library for handling 2D/3D large UMP management. We nee more information on your environment. Are you running on Android OS 2.1+?

Most likely you need to compile this yourself and then adb push it to your device. It looks like you'er running on a tegra tablet dev kit, is this the case?

http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/drivers/open-source-mali-gpus-linux-kernel-device-drivers.php